# Spring rest + JPA + H2 @ManyToOne bidirectional relationship. Unable to store child entities

Tags: spring, jpa, one-to-many, h2, many-to-one

I've some troubles trying to store some entities with JPA, the situation is the following:

1. WebMessageEntity.java

   ```
   @EqualsAndHashCode
   @Data
   @Entity(name = "web_message")
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @Builder
   public class WebMessageEntity{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Getter
   @Column(name = "WEB_MESSAGE_ID")
   private Long id;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotEmpty
   private String hotelTicker;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private WebMessageColor color;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name = "message_type")
   private WebMessageType type;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private ReservationStep step;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name = "message_trigger")
   private WebMessageTrigger trigger;

   private int duration;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private WebMessagePosition position;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   private boolean isActive;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   @Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
   private LocalDate startDate;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   @Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
   private LocalDate endDate;

   @Setter
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "webMessage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @NotNull
   private List<WebMessageTranslationEntity> translations;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotEmpty
   private String userName;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NotNull
   @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
   private LocalDateTime creationDate;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   private String modifiedBy;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
   private LocalDateTime modificationDate;


   //constructors
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



   private WebMessageEntity(String hotelTicker, WebMessageColor color, WebMessageType type, ReservationStep step,
                            WebMessageTrigger trigger, boolean isActive, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate,
                            List<WebMessageTranslationEntity> translations, String userName, LocalDateTime creationDate,
                            String modifiedBy, LocalDateTime modificationDate)
   {
       this.hotelTicker = hotelTicker;
       this.color = color;
       this.type = type;
       this.step = step;
       this.trigger = trigger;
       this.isActive = isActive;
       this.startDate = startDate;
       this.endDate = endDate;
       this.translations = translations;
       this.userName = userName;
       this.creationDate = creationDate;
       this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
       this.modificationDate = modificationDate;
   }

   private WebMessageEntity(String hotelTicker, WebMessageColor color, WebMessageType type, ReservationStep step,
                           WebMessageTrigger trigger, int duration, WebMessagePosition position, boolean isActive,
                           LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, List<WebMessageTranslationEntity> translations,
                           String userName, LocalDateTime creationDate, String modifiedBy, LocalDateTime modificationDate)
   {
       this.hotelTicker = hotelTicker;
       this.color = color;
       this.type = type;
       this.step = step;
       this.trigger = trigger;
       this.setDuration(duration);
       this.setPosition(position);
       this.isActive = isActive;
       this.startDate = startDate;
       this.endDate = endDate;
       this.translations = translations;
       this.userName = userName;
       this.creationDate = creationDate;
       this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
       this.modificationDate = modificationDate;
   }

   //GETTERS, SETTERS and some private field verification methods
   ```
2. WebMessageTranslationEntity

   ```
   @Data
   @EqualsAndHashCode
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @Builder
   @Entity(name = "web_message_translation")
   @Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames =                 {"locale", "message_id"}))
   public class WebMessageTranslationEntity {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Getter
       @Column(name = "MESSAGE_TRANSLATION_ID")
       private Long id;

       @NotEmpty
       private String content;

       @NotEmpty
       private String locale;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
       private WebMessageEntity webMessage;

   }
   ```
3. @Controller

   ```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/api")
   public class WebMessageResource {


       private final WebMessageService messageService;

       @Autowired
       public WebMessageResource(WebMessageService messageService) {
       this.messageService = messageService;
       }


       @PostMapping("{hotelTicker}/messages")
       public ResponseEntity<?> createMessage(@RequestBody @Valid     WebMessageDTO dto, @PathVariable @NotNull String hotelTicker) {


           if (verifyHotelTicker(dto, hotelTicker)) {

               WebMessageEntity newEntity =         messageService.store(fromWebMessageDTOToEntity(dto));

               HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

               //TODO rebuild URI with exact path to access resource
           headers.setLocation(ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(FilterEntity.class).slash(newEntity.getHotelTicker()).slash(newEntity.getId()).toUri());

           return new ResponseEntity<>(fromWebMessageEntityToDTO(newEntity), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);

       }

       return new ResponseEntity<>("Hotel ticker specified in URI doesn't match with DTO's hotel ticker", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

   }

   private boolean verifyHotelTicker(WebMessageDTO dto, String hotelTicker) {
       return hotelTicker.equals(dto.getHotelTicker());
   }

   private List<WebMessageTranslationEntity> fromTranslationDTOsToEntities(List<WebMessageTranslationDTO> translationDTOs) {

       return translationDTOs
               .stream()
               .map(translation -> WebMessageTranslationEntity
                       .builder()
                       .content(translation.getContent())
                       .locale(translation.getLocale())
                       .build())
                   .collect(toList());

       }

       private WebMessageEntity fromWebMessageDTOToEntity(WebMessageDTO webMessageDTOs) {

           return WebMessageEntity
                   .builder()
                   .hotelTicker(webMessageDTOs.getHotelTicker())
                   .color(webMessageDTOs.getColor())
                   .type(webMessageDTOs.getType())
                   .step(webMessageDTOs.getStep())
                   .trigger(webMessageDTOs.getTrigger())
                   .duration(webMessageDTOs.getDuration())
                   .position(webMessageDTOs.getPosition())
                   .isActive(webMessageDTOs.getIsActive())
                   .startDate(webMessageDTOs.getStartDate())
                   .endDate(webMessageDTOs.getEndDate())
                   .userName(webMessageDTOs.getUserName())
                   .creationDate(webMessageDTOs.getCreationDate())
                   .modifiedBy(webMessageDTOs.getModifiedBy())
                   .modificationDate(webMessageDTOs.getModificationDate())
                   .translations(this.fromTranslationDTOsToEntities(webMessageDTOs.getTransla    tions()))
                   .build();
   }

   private WebMessageDTO fromWebMessageEntityToDTO(WebMessageEntity webMessageEntity) {

       return WebMessageDTO
               .builder()
               .id(webMessageEntity.getId())
               .hotelTicker(webMessageEntity.getHotelTicker())
               .color(webMessageEntity.getColor())
               .type(webMessageEntity.getType())
               .step(webMessageEntity.getStep())
               .trigger(webMessageEntity.getTrigger())
               .duration(webMessageEntity.getDuration())
               .position(webMessageEntity.getPosition())
               .isActive(webMessageEntity.isActive())
               .startDate(webMessageEntity.getStartDate())
               .endDate(webMessageEntity.getEndDate())
               .userName(webMessageEntity.getUserName())
               .creationDate(webMessageEntity.getCreationDate())
               .modifiedBy(webMessageEntity.getModifiedBy())
               .modificationDate(webMessageEntity.getModificationDate())
               .translations(this.fromTranslationEntitiesToDTO(webMessageEntity.getTranslations()))
               .build();
   }

   private List<WebMessageTranslationDTO> fromTranslationEntitiesToDTO(List<WebMessageTranslationEntity> translationEntities) {

       return translationEntities
               .stream()
               .map(translation -> WebMessageTranslationDTO
                       .builder()
                       //.id(translation.getId())
                       .content(translation.getContent())
                       .locale(translation.getLocale())
                       .build())
               .collect(toList());
   }


   }
   ```
4. StackTrace

   ```
   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column     
   "MESSAGE_ID"; SQL statement:
   insert into web_message_translation (message_translation_id, content,locale, message_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23502-194]
       at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
       at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
       at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
       at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:311)
       at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:793)
       at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
       at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
       at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
       at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
       ...
   ```
5. Table creation YAML file

   ```
   - changeSet:
     id: '008-1'
     author: arnau
     comment: 'create table web_message'
     preConditions:
       - onFail: MARK_RAN
       - onFailMessage: 'Table already exists, must be production environment...'
       - not:
         - tableExists:
             tableName: web_message
     changes:
     - createTable:
         tableName: web_message
         columns:
         - column:
             name: WEB_MESSAGE_ID
             type: NUMBER
             autoIncrement: true
             constraints:
               primaryKey: true
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: hotel_ticker
             type: VARCHAR(155)
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: color
             type: VARCHAR(255)
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: message_type
             type: VARCHAR(255)
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: step
             type: VARCHAR(255)
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: message_trigger
             type: VARCHAR(255)
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: duration
             type: NUMBER
             constraints:
               nullable: true
         - column:
             name: position
             type: VARCHAR(255)
             constraints:
               nullable: true
         - column:
             name: is_active
             type: BOOLEAN(1)
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: start_date
             type: DATE
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: end_date
             type: DATE
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: user_name
             type: VARCHAR(255)
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: creation_date
             type: TIMESTAMP
             constraints:
               nullable: false
         - column:
             name: modified_by
             type: VARCHAR(255)
             constraints:
               nullable: true
         - column:
             name: modification_date
             type: TIMESTAMP
             constraints:
               nullable: true


   - changeSet:
         id: '008-2'
         author: arnau
         comment: 'create table web_message_translation'
         preConditions:
           - onFail: MARK_RAN
           - onFailMessage: 'Table already exists, must be production environment...'
           - not:
             - tableExists:
                 tableName: web_message_translation
         changes:
         - createTable:
             tableName: web_message_translation
             columns:
             - column:
                 name: MESSAGE_TRANSLATION_ID
                 type: NUMBER
                 autoIncrement: true
                 constraints:
                   primaryKey: true
                   nullable: false
             - column:
                 name: locale
                 type: VARCHAR(2)
                 constraints:
                   unique: true
                   nullable: false
             - column:
                 name: content
                 type: VARCHAR(255)
                 constraints:
                   nullable: false
             - column:
                 name: message_id
                 type: CHAR(22)
                 constraints:
                   nullable: false
                   references: web_message(WEB_MESSAGE_ID)
                   foreignKeyName:     fk_web_message_translation__web_message
     - changeSet:
         id: '008-3'
         author: arnau
         comment: 'Add unique constraint by locale and web_message_id'
         changes:
         - addUniqueconstraint:
           tableName: web_message_translation
           columnNames: locale, message_id
           constraintName: uc_locale__message_id
   ```

The problem is that when I try to store those entities, JPA tries to store the entity `webMessageTranslationEntity` with NULL value in the column `message_id` and obviously, this is rejected by the DB because this field is setted as NOT NULL.

How can I store those entities with this requisites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@NotNull
private List<WebMessageTranslationEntity> translations;
```

This will set constraint on the foreign key to not be null

1. Keep the constraint and inject a persisted WebMessageEntity
2. Keep the constraint and inject a none persisted WebMessageEntity but you will need to set the cascade in the WebMessageEntity side to persist (or ALL)
3. change the constraint by removing @NotNull

Comment: Changing the constraint is not an option, so I tried to add a CascadeType.ALL at WebMessageEntity property of WebMessageTranslation entit, like this:

    `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
     private WebMessageEntity webMessage;`

But the problem persists, so finally I had to persist th entities individually, persisting WebMessageEntity at first and then persist WebMessageTranslations. But I think that has to be a cleaner way to do it. I'll take it as solved but if I find a better way I'll post it here. Thank's a lot @AmerQarabsa

Comment: the cascade define the cascading of the operation on the child entity, so if you have A which has a reference to B, and you want to persist the referenced B when persisting A , you would define the cascade inside A on the relation of the B reference, so in your cane it should be in the OneToMany not the ManyToOne